# How to reset PostgreSQL's primary key sequence for all tables when it falls out of sync?

Tags: postgresql

After an import to a database through a tool like Postico, or other, the ID sequence for tables fall out of sync.

I've learnt that I can fix this by running

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name)+1);
```

but how would I do this for all tables, without having to run the same command for each?

Answer (score 2):

I've actually found an answer.

Create a file `reset.sql` with this as the content:

```
SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
       quote_literal(quote_ident(PGT.schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(S.relname)) ||
       ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(C.attname)|| '), 1) ) FROM ' ||
       quote_ident(PGT.schemaname)|| '.'||quote_ident(T.relname)|| ';'
FROM pg_class AS S,
     pg_depend AS D,
     pg_class AS T,
     pg_attribute AS C,
     pg_tables AS PGT
WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
    AND S.oid = D.objid
    AND D.refobjid = T.oid
    AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
    AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
    AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
ORDER BY S.relname;
```

Run this file as

```
psql -h yourdb.yourhost.com -U mysecretuser -Atq -f reset.sql -o temp
```

Then run the output as

```
psql -h yourdb.yourhost.com -U mysecretuser -f temp
```

And finally

```
rm temp
```

Comment: Running the first command, I get the error: `reset.sql: No such file or directory`

Comment: @kunambi You have to create the file with the content shared at the top of the answer.